# mat-sort not working for drop down column

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have listing page with name and department. here department column is drop down value. when I try to sort based on name it's working fine, but sorting is not working for drop down value.

here is my code

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-list>
        <mat-table #table1 [dataSource]="this.dataSource" #matSort="matSort" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="dept">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Department </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
                    <mat-select [(value)]="element.dept">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let department of departments" [value]="department.name">
                        {{department.name}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator [length]="length" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[10,15]" [pageIndex]="pageIndex" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    </mat-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you sorting it? do you use method array.sort((a, b) => ...) ?

Comment: It is default sorting provided by angular